# How to change Laravel from Localhost to live ip adress?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, digital-ocean

I am deploying a Laravel application on digitalocean cloud server using LAMP. The app uses Vuejs so, therefore, I post data from the database to a URL called /proapi and fetch it using Axios. The data is correctly received when I am on localhost:8000 but when I deployed the application to the live IP address it fails saying the following:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8000/proapi/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
```

I presumed that the .env file was to blame so I changed the APP_URL to my current live IP address but it still gives the same error. Where can I change the URL to ensure that this error is resolved?

Comment: I did then used the sudo apache2 restart command to restart the server but it still doesn't change the error

Comment: You need to post your `Vue` code as it seems that's the code that hits the route (not Laravel)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the root folder of your application and change the following lines in the **.env** file:

```
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

to:

```
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://mywebsite.com
```

Comment: Have you changed this settings in the production machine? Usually the env file is in the git ignore